# Sound no longer recognized after latest kernel upgrade (14.04)

Tags: 14.04, sound, kernel, pulseaudio, alsa

This morning Software Updater showed notification of new updates.  The kernel was part of the update which then required a reboot.  Once I rebooted, my sound was gone and no longer recognized buy the system.  I have tried all I know to do: restart ALSA (forcibly), unload alsa and pulseaudio and re-install both, none of these has worked.

I need the sound back on this machine ASAP and like an idiot, I have already purged previous kernels from the system before I completely checked everything.

Here is the results of uname -a:

```
Linux z600-ubuntu-64-bit 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:28:38 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

## UPDATE:

Ok, sound IS working, just not pulseaudio and the sound notifier (speaker icon).  I also noticed that most of my system settings are missing in the control panel.  What I have in the control panels is:

Language Support, Security & Privacy, Printers, Landscape Service, and Software and Updates.

That's it. Any ideas?

## CONFIGS:

$ cat /etc/pulse/daemon.conf

```
# This file is part of PulseAudio.
#
# PulseAudio is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# PulseAudio is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but
# WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU
# General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public License
# along with PulseAudio; if not, write to the Free Software
# Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307
# USA.

## Configuration file for the PulseAudio daemon. See pulse-daemon.conf(5) for
## more information. Default values are commented out.  Use either ; or # for
## commenting.

; daemonize = no
; fail = yes
; allow-module-loading = yes
; allow-exit = yes
; use-pid-file = yes
; system-instance = no
; local-server-type = user
; enable-shm = yes
; shm-size-bytes = 0 # setting this 0 will use the system-default, usually 64 MiB
; lock-memory = no
; cpu-limit = no

; high-priority = yes
; nice-level = -11

; realtime-scheduling = yes
; realtime-priority = 5

; exit-idle-time = 20
; scache-idle-time = 20

; dl-search-path = (depends on architecture)

; load-default-script-file = yes
; default-script-file = /etc/pulse/default.pa

; log-target = auto
; log-level = notice
; log-meta = no
; log-time = no
; log-backtrace = 0

resample-method = speex-float-1
; enable-remixing = yes
; enable-lfe-remixing = no

flat-volumes = no

; rlimit-fsize = -1
; rlimit-data = -1
; rlimit-stack = -1
; rlimit-core = -1
; rlimit-as = -1
; rlimit-rss = -1
; rlimit-nproc = -1
; rlimit-nofile = 256
; rlimit-memlock = -1
; rlimit-locks = -1
; rlimit-sigpending = -1
; rlimit-msgqueue = -1
; rlimit-nice = 31
; rlimit-rtprio = 9
; rlimit-rttime = 1000000

; default-sample-format = s16le
; default-sample-rate = 44100
; alternate-sample-rate = 48000
; default-sample-channels = 2
; default-channel-map = front-left,front-right

default-fragments = 8
default-fragment-size-msec = 10

; enable-deferred-volume = yes
deferred-volume-safety-margin-usec = 1
; deferred-volume-extra-delay-usec = 0
```

There is no ~/.pulse/default.pa

Also, I have an Aferglow Wireless Headset.  After the MOST recent update, my headset works, but the microphone is no longer recognized or working.  It works in Windows/MAC OSX though.

Comment: Ok, seem to be making SOME progress.  When I reboot, I hear a tone when the login screen comes up, but once I login - no sound and pulseaudio is not running.  When I try to run pulseaudio, I get this error:

E: [pulseaudio] module.c: Module "module-udev-detect" should be loaded once at most. Refusing to load.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Module load failed.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to initialize daemon.

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/534121/edit) button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Comment: Please include the version of your Pulseaudio installation and the content of `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` and `~/.pulse/default.pa`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found the issue.  There were some driver artifacts left behind during the upgrade in the .default stopping pulse audio from working correctly.  When I removed them, everything started to work normally.